# How to source multiple files in R without returning value ($value) and visible ($visible) traces

Tags: r

Say I have the following `.R` files:

**R/01_script.R**

```
cat("You are now in 01_script.R")
```

**R/01_script.R**

```
cat("You are now in 01_script.R")
```

I would to put these into a separate call / file `WORKFLOW.R` which sources both of these files:

**WORKFLOW.R**

```
source(here::here("R/01_script.R"))
source(here::here("R/02_script.R"))
```

Running this, I obtain the following printed to the console:

```
You are now in 01_script.R
You are now in 02_script.R
```

If I try to abstract this into a list and then run `sapply`, `lapply`, or `purrr::map`, I receive more verbose output:

```
list_of_scripts <- list(
  here::here("R/01_script.R"),
  here::here("R/02_script.R")
)

lapply(list_of_scripts, source)
# You are now in 01_script.RYou are now in 02_script.R[[1]]
# [[1]]$value
# NULL
# 
# [[1]]$visible
# [1] FALSE
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]]$value
# NULL
# 
# [[2]]$visible
# [1] FALSE

# ...and similar results with either...
sapply(list_of_scripts, source)

# ...or this...
library(tidyverse)
list_of_scripts %>% 
  map(source)
```

I am not understanding the documentation of `source()` and have not been able to remove the verbose output. I have tried various combinations of `echo = FALSE`, `print.eval = FALSE`, `withAutoPrint(print. = FALSE)`, etc. but the console prints the `$value` and `$visible` variables in a list structure.

Is there a way to abstract calling `source()` on multiple files and keep a "clean" console output? Even better if the output from `cat()` could automatically insert newlines `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible option:

```
file_path = "/path/to/dir"
```

now list all R scripts you'd like to source:

```
r_scritps_source = list.files(file_path, recursive = T, full.names = T, pattern = ".R")
```

and now:

```
invisible(lapply(r_scripts_source, source))
```

or more compact:

```
invisible(lapply(list.files(file_path, recursive = T, full.names = T, pattern = ".R"), source))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the `lapply` in a function that returns invisibly:

```
silent_lapply <- function(...) invisible(lapply(...))

silent_lapply(list_of_scripts, source)
#> You are now in 01_script.R
#> You are now in 02_script.R
```